# Is C++ machine-independent or machine-dependent?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++14, c++20

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-c-programming-language/
Under some keys & features

> Machine Independent but Platform Dependent: A C++ executable is not platform-independent (compiled programs on Linux won’t run on Windows), however they are machine-independent.

1. **Platform-Independent:** This part of the statement correctly points out that C++ executables are not platform-independent. Programs compiled on one operating system (e.g., Linux) often won't run directly on another operating system (e.g., Windows) because of differences in system libraries, system calls, and executable file formats.
2. **Machine-Independent:** The term "machine independent" in this context can be misleading or imprecise. Compiled C++ executables are not truly machine-independent either. They are machine-dependent because they are compiled down to machine code specific to the target CPU architecture. Code compiled for an x86 architecture, for example, won't run on an ARM-based machine.

So why, in every article, is it written that C++ is machine-independent?

C++ executables are **neither** platform-independent (they depend on the operating system) **nor** machine-independent (they depend on the CPU architecture). They are specific to both the platform and machine.

In practice, if you want to run a C++ program on different platforms or machines, you typically need to recompile it for each specific platform and architecture.`

Please clarify what is true: Here, I want to know that what a machine-independent language looks like. "x86-64 Windows" and "Arm Windows" are two different platforms and the executable file created by compilation for x86-64 Windows Platform will not be executable on "ARM Windows", due to different CPU architecture. This shows that C++ is platform dependent; so, how can we define machine-dependence or machine-independence here? How can we say that C++ is a machine-dependent language if the executable file of one platform doesn't run on other platforms?

Comment: The site you linked is not known for quality articles and correct information.

Comment: "Platform" usually includes both OS and the architecture, I believe. "Machine-independent" likely is intended to mean that you can compile on one machine and run on a different one that uses the same/similar OS and architecture.

Comment: Note that this is for *compiled* executable programs. The C++ language itself is totally platform independent. A standard C++ source code, not using any platform (OS) specific features, should be possible to build for any platform (OS) and machine. You are mixing the two concepts.

Comment: But here the author is talking about executable file...which is platform dependent and machine independent, so how it's possible,, when the program is compiled then it becomes platform dependent as well as machine dependent,, that's why the executable file can not be run on any other machine,,, do how he has written platform independent

Comment: There is no such thing as c++ executable. Executable files are platform dependent, limited to be run on some particual platform or a set  of related platforms (hell, even java ones). Most "platform-independant""execuatbles" are  in fact,  modules consisting of instructions for a interpreter, which , in turn, is platform dependant.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Machine Language code is stored in an .exe file which is abbreviated as executable code

Comment: Lets say you have two Windows machines in your office. You build a program (using any language, really) and it can run on the machine you used to build it on. Then you copy the executable program to the second Windows machine. You can run it there too. Two different machines, same program executable. It's machine independent.

Comment: @Reborne that once was known as p-compiler (pseudocode compiler). And exe file isn't platform dindependant.It tags itself on which OS family it can run.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the concept u explained me is applicable when we just have the source code ....at the initial stage ...but when we compile the source code on a machine A and platform (windows)the executable file .EXE is generated then we cannot use that. .EXE file on other machine B of same platform...so how come it is said to be machine independent

Comment: Okay, lets say you download an installer from the Internet. Install it on two machines. You can still run the program on both machines, right? Again, machine independent. And again, language isn't relevant.

Comment: *"we cannot use that. .EXE file on other machine B of same platform"* No, you of course can do that.

Comment: There is alot of wrong with that article. E.g, right away `It is an imperative and a compiled language.` No. C++ is not imperative, though it got element of such. In fact, it's declarative language in first place, object-oriented, concept-oriented, functional language (and saying it is "functional" renders "imperative" void) with static typesystem.  Second, it doesn't specify it has to be compiled. The term is "translation",  Implementation of translator tool and used libraries (a.k.a. "implementation") and how result is executed is NOT specified by language.

Comment: perhaps relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/209703/why-wont-windows-exe-files-work-on-linux

Comment: An executable compiled on one Windows machine can run on another Windows machine, and same for any other OS. Otherwise it would be impossible to download a compiled application and one would have to build everything from source on their own machine, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as u said "" "we cannot use that. .EXE file on other machine B of same platform" No, you of course can do that."" They are machine-dependent because they are compiled down to machine code specific to the target CPU architecture. Code compiled for an x86 architecture, for example, won't run on an ARM-based machine.

Comment: x86 and ARM targets are different *platforms*.

Comment: Well, and techinically , if you have a proper loader shell, any "executable" can be run on other machine. It's a problem of OS to support that. And I'm pretty sure there is such "loader" for Linux that can do that for _some_ PEXE-formatted files (ie.. for compatible instruction set ones).

Comment: As Someprogrammerdude said, ARM and x86 are different platforms. If you have two machines, both are e.g. x86, and both run Windows, then the same .EXE can work on both.

Comment: Okay but it's partially machine independent....

Comment: You misunderstood the definition of platform. "x86-64 Windows" and "Arm Windows" are "two" platforms instead of the same platforms. Definition of a platform mostly including OS and CPU architecture in most of cases. "machine independent" means "when the platform they're used is the same, machines doesn't matter". You *may* invent your own definitions but elaborate them before discussing them.

Comment: @LouisGo as u said that  "x86-64 Windows" and "Arm Windows" are "two" different platforms , and the executable file created on compilation on x86-64 Windows Platform, will not be executable on "ARM Windows" this shows the platform dependent ,,, due to different CPU architecture I got this but,,,,, I am not able to understand what do you want to say by machines doesn't matter, if platform is there machine will automatically be there  overall i did not get the meaning of machine independent you want to convey...

Comment: The *language* is completely independent from the machine or platform. You'd be writing the same code whether you're on Windows, or Linux, or on another computer. It's the *executable* that you get from the code that might or might not run (correctly).

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing about machine independent for you. If one purchases two machine with the same CPU arch and installed with the same OS. If the same binary works on both machine then it's machine independent. Please elaborate on your confusion. Give examples which you think they the same and examples that you feel they're not machine independent. Emphasize again, machine independent is not a standalone concept, but with a presumption that "platform of the machines" are the same. Also here we do not discuss dll which makes the discussion more complex. Presume standalone executable.

Comment: @LouisGo  C++ executables are machine-dependent because they are compiled to run on a specific CPU architecture.

To accurately describe it:

"A C++ executable is not platform-independent (compiled programs on Linux won't run on Windows), and they are also not machine independent, as they are compiled for a specific CPU architecture."

This revised statement accurately reflects that C++ executables depend on both the platform (operating system) and the machine's architecture

Comment: Ok just found machine independent includes CPU architecture in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-dependent_software#:~:text=Applications%20that%20run%20on%20multiple,and%20will%20attract%20more%20buyers.). In this case, only jvm-ish runtime are machine independent. Though I always consider "OS+Architecture" as a platform. Not much to argue. cc @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: There do not exist "C++ executables". C++ is text. Conforming compiler makes that  text executable for particular platform.

Comment: @LouisGo I guess, that's where Wikipedia doesn't comply to ISO definitions. One you're iusing is ISO-based. That's how norms define "platform".

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, could you name the iso number or a reference to it? I tried to search but didn't find iso related documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ is generally considered a machine-independent programming language. It is designed to be platform-agnostic, which means that C++ code can be written to be portable across different computer architectures and operating systems. This is achieved through the use of a compiler, which translates C++ source code into machine code that is specific to the target platform.

While C++ itself is machine-independent, the compiled code it generates is machine-dependent. In other words, the same C++ source code can be compiled to run on different machines, but you need a compiler for each specific platform to generate executable code. This means that C++ programs can run on various systems as long as there is a compatible compiler for that system.